# Prove that no disconnected framework exists

Tags: graph-theory

> Ten points in space, no three of which are collinear, are connected, each oneto all the others, by a total of $45$ line segments. The resulting framework $F$ will be “disconnected” into two disjoint nonempty parts by the removal of one point from the interior of each of the 9 segments emanating from any one vertex off. Prove that $F$ cannot be similarly disconnected by the removal of only $8$ points from the interiors of the 45 segments.

If anyone could provide a diagram to explain this that would help because I am having difficulty visualizing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this picture, in which ten points are completely connected to each other:

[image: Complete graph on 10 vertices]

You then choose some point, which I have designated by the green arrow. From this point, you delete $9$ interior points from each of the edges going from this point.

[image: 9 points chosen]

Here you see the picture, where the $9$ points have been deleted. The vertex with the green arrow is no longer connected to any other vertex. All its edges have been severed.

[image: 9 points deleted]

In fact, it is easier to see, if you delete the $9$ edges all together instead of just deleting $9$ points:

[image: 9 edges deleted]

The exercise is to prove that no matter how you choose $8$ edges, you cannot make the graph disconnected, if you delete these edges.

Comment: Oh okay. By disconnected it means that not having that one point in the diagram anymore?

Comment: Isn't the proof simple then? To disconnect any vertex you must take away at least $9$ points in the interiors of $9$ edges.

Comment: @JohnRyan I'm not sure it's that simple (even though it makes sense intuitively). Maybe you don't need to choose the $8$ points on edges coming out of the same point. Maybe you can disconnected the framework by having $5$ points (only connected to one another) on one side, and $5$ points on the other side.

Comment: In order to disconnect the frame we must disconnect a point. And in order to do that we  must take away at least $9$ interior points of the $9$ edges right?

Comment: @JohnRyan To disconnect the frame, we must disconnect a chunk of points. Maybe we disconnect two points, like the one with the green arrow and its neighbor. These two points can still be connected to one another, but not to any other point of the graph. I believe you need to argue that you can disconnect to chunkof points by removing only $8$ edges.

Comment: @JohnRyan I would probably argue as follows. Suppose you have disconnected the framework into two pieces. One piece contains $k$ points, the other piece contains the rest, which is $10-k$ points. Then I would count how many edges had to be deleted to make this disconnection, i.e. for each of the $k$ points in the one piece, the edge to each of the $10-k$ points in the other piece have been removed.

Comment: I thought the one with the green arrow disconnected $1$ point.

Comment: @JohnRyan yeah, it does. But maybe I can disconnect more points by removing another set of edges.